# MacBook Pro 13 2017 short shift

Tags: keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 model with short left shift, ` button next to it and § is where ` is supposed to be. Can I change my layout so that ` works as a shift and § is changed to **`** ?

I tried using Ukelele, but it does not recognize the keyboard correctly (or am I missing something?)

[image: keyboard]

Comment: Where any key is "supposed to be" is entirely dependant on what language the keyboard is. We'd need that information to even start to help. See https://support.apple.com/HT201794

Comment: The layout chosen is Polish Pro. `Is supposed to be` is based on previous keyboards used.

Comment: Not the selected 'software' layout - the actual physical keyboard layout. Only the US keyboard has the weird long shift key with nothing between that & the z. All the others, as far as I'm aware, have the short key & often, but not always, the backtick & tilde key next to it.

Comment: You have a mac with Polish keyboard.

Comment: Pick you keyboard from here https://keyshorts.com/blogs/blog/37615873-how-to-identify-macbook-keyboard-localization

Comment: So the physical layout is US international (thanks @Buscar). The task at hand is to bind \` to act as a longer shift, and use § as \`. Can that be done?

Comment: The layout is strictly **English, International (Z)** not US International - as listed in my original link.

Comment: I do understand that. But with a magical use of software you can sometimes change what a key does. For example my CapsLock acts as Escape key. Now I need to make \` act as a shift.